# Does NoSQL databases have a common language like SQL?

Tags: json, nosql

I am trying to learn NoSQL databases with a focus on the JSON/key-value type. According to [this blog from redis](https://redis.com/blog/what-are-json-databases/)

> Column, graph, key-value, in-memory, and document are all different
> types of NoSQL databases

As a postgres user, a first question I have is:

*Is there a common query language for the key-value type (JSON type) NoSQL databases, which can be used across multiple NoSQL databases? (just as SQL for relational databases)*

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a common query language for the key-value type (JSON type) NoSQL databases, which can be used across multiple NoSQL databases? (just as SQL for relational databases)*

Nope.

Just depends on the NoSQL database system and the application layer language you're using to interface with it. Some NoSQL databases do actually use a SQL-like language even.